# Inner hits on doubly nested field in bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a bool query to find a query string in several fields in my document. I would like to use highlighting to show which field(s) matched to cause the return of the document. I have the below query working to tell me whether the non-nested field (the first in the should array) matched, but I can't figure out how to get the highlight for the doubly nested part.

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "boost": 100.0,
              "query": "queryString"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "boost": 1.0,
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "nested1.nested2.name": {
                      "query": "queryString"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path": "nested1.nested2"
              }
            },
            "path": "nested1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
 },
 "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "m_szTopicName": {}
    }
  }
```

I have tried adding an inner hits highlight at the same level as the `"path": "nested1.nested2"` but that doesn't seem to return anything (and I have results which aren't getting highlights on the working part, so I assume they must be matching the doubly nested query).

```
"inner_hits": {
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "nested1.nested2.name": {}
        }
    }
}
```